# Apk crashes when Release mode but in debug mode works perfectly

Tags: android, react-native, sdk

I have get apk with release mode, but app crash.but apk with debug apk is not crash
this is my android/app/build.gradle

```
signingConfigs {
    debug {
        storeFile file('debug.keystore')
        storePassword 'android'
        keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
        keyPassword 'android'
    } } 
   buildTypes {
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
    release {
        // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
        // see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
    } }
```

my react-native version is "react-native": "^0.62.2", and

```
ext { 
  buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3" 
  minSdkVersion = 16 
  compileSdkVersion = 28 
  targetSdkVersion = 28 
}
```

Comment: post your logcat

Comment: my react-native version is  "react-native": "^0.62.2",and

Comment: ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
    }

Comment: please post the error message and your app's manifest

Answer (score 0):

Usually that's related to proguard obfuscation, you can check that commenting out the following lines:

```
   minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
   proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
```

if that helps - you'll need to adjust somehow proguard-rules.pro avoid renaming some classes.

To find what exactly causes the crash debug using `adb logcat` command (or just look at the "Run" window in Android Studio).